# Is it OK to promote a non-working SQL Fiddle?

Tags: discussion

The [sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql) promotes SQLFiddle in its description. It says:

> Questions should include code examples, table structure, sample data, [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) and a tag for the DBMS implementation (e.g. MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, MS SQL Server, IBM DB2) being used.

However, SQL Fiddle is not really working. For Oracle you can't even build a simple schema with the following error being displayed:

[image: SQLFiddle for Oracle]

For other database types it is also useless most of the time, as any more or less complex query result in the timeouts.

Do not get me wrong: I like the tool; it is just getting worse and worse by day.

I think the mention of SQL Fiddle should be removed from the [sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql) until it is fixed.

Comment: The script you shown works with mysql, but fails with oracle databases

Comment: It also fails with MS SQL server

Comment: SQLFiddle is really going down. Does not work most of the time for me too. Just sad. I used it a lot and not hardly any more.

Comment: I used to use SQL Fiddle to provide a working example of most of my Oracle SQL answers but [looking at my history](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a1509264%20%5boracle%5d%20fiddle) I haven't used it for Oracle answers since Dec 2015 (with the exception of a couple of odd instances which are mostly when multiple languages are tagged and the fiddle is for a non-Oracle language). In the last 6+ months I haven't even attempted to access Oracle fiddles as I just assume it is broken and won't work.

Comment: @juergen d Due to this situation with sql fiddle I've decided to add support to rextester [mysql](http://rextester.com/l/mysql), [sql server](http://rextester.com/l/sql_server), postgre and oracle are coming soon. Check it out!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It is not a bad question (from a meta newbie POV).

The author is part of the Stack Overflow community. Try reaching out to him and see if issues can be mitigated / worked out. Perhaps it's temporary trouble?

Also, before he was allowed to modify the tag wiki he waited for two years, until the tool caught on with community [(and HE was the one to ask if it's appropriate)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120507/i-built-a-sql-version-of-jsfiddle-is-it-appropriate-to-update-the-sql-tag-wiki). I'd say, removing it now, may be too hasty.

I don't claim to have monitored the situation for weeks, though. It's actually the first time I learned about the tool. I'd still prefer you to try talking with the author first though (he's the OP of question I linked).

Comment: OK. Thanks for the suggestion. Will try to contact him

Answer (score 20):

Sorry everyone! I know the site has been performing poorly lately. It's not easy to keep a hobby site going indefinitely (over four years now!). I work full time and have a family - time to make things work smoothly does not come cheaply. It's not a question of money, even - it's mainly about time. I feel badly that people haven't had the great experience with it that they used to have. I have some ideas about how I could make it better, the real issue is executing those ideas. Thoughts welcome

Comment: Recruit some help!

Comment: One idea might be to show that the project is on GitHub more prominently (i.e. have a link with the GitHub icon on the homepage, instead of on the about page).

Comment: Github thing unlikely to work, those who would want to help have all the info they need. The real solution is stackoverflow investing into projects like these, otherwise they will sooner or later die.