# Restore SQL Fiddle link for [sql] tag wiki

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki

After far too long, I have some good news about the status of [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com). I have rolled out a new backend which I feel is much more reliable than the previous version (see [Is it OK to promote a non-working SQL Fiddle?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321437/is-it-ok-to-promote-a-non-working-sql-fiddle) )

People seem to be using it successfully: [SQL Fiddle usage](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=url%3a%22http%3a%2f%2f*sqlfiddle.com%2f*%22)

If you are curious about the implementation, it's all on [github](https://github.com/jakefeasel/sqlfiddle3) (and I would certainly love to have help with it if anyone is interested in contributing).

To that end, if you all think it is worthwhile, it may be worth considering adding back the text on the sql wiki that was removed with this change: 
https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/3607304/52

Cheers everyone!

Comment: I have submitted the edit [proposal](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/16639564).

Comment: I've also added details [about other fiddle sites](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/3607304/revisions) whilst we are at it.

Comment: Oh, good. I was pretty bummed when this broke.

Comment: @canon me too. It's hard when you invest a lot of your time and effort into something and see it flounder. I feel much more confident in the new version, though.

Comment: It's broken right now, if you're not confident you can keep it online then perhaps we need to be a bit more careful about using it in posts? Not a complaint about your service, it's fantastic when it does work and highly appreciated.

Comment: Must have been a temporary hiccup. Seems fine now. The challenge is when people intentionally send ridiculous queries, it can cause problems temporarily.

Answer (score 15):

[People seemed to have found it useful](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321437/is-it-ok-to-promote-a-non-working-sql-fiddle#comment335772_321437), so if you are confident that it is now reasonably stable and usable, then it makes good sense to edit the link back in. At least, I can't see how it would *hurt* anything.

[kayess got the ball rolling](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351822/restore-sql-fiddle-link-for-sql-tag-wiki#comment488904_351822); I improved their suggested edit by adding back in some of the original context/advice that [used to be there](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/3607304/52), and made a few other changes. These updates are now [live](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/info).

Following on from [your issue of time to maintain it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/321570/366904), may I humbly suggest that you [recruit some help from the Stack Overflow community](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/12/19/free-vote-based-advertising-for-open-source-projects/). The current ad repository is [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349017/open-source-advertising-2017).